# Squash first N commits of git history / keep the rest as is

Tags: git, rebase

Consider the following problem:

- Private Project containing some credentials in the early stages
- We want to go open source
- We need to get rid of the credentials in the history
- credentials are not in single files but in code
- Complicated history with several merges, pull requests etc.

What I want to do:

Squash all commits from root up to an arbitrary commit with *clean* state to one big 'Initial commit'.

When I do:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

And squash the first commits together:

```
pick Initial commit \
fixup dirty1        |
fixup dirty2        | Squash these to one, to remove credentials.
fixup dirty3        |
fixup clean1        /
pick clean2
pick clean3
...
...
```

I have to rebase everything and resolve all merge conflicts again after that.

How can I just squash the first N commits without having to resolve the entire history including the merge conflicts after the N + 1 commit.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way around rewriting the entire history. This because when clean2 gets its new parent (the squashed commit), its hash changes. This means that clean3 has a new parent, which changes its hash, and so on and so on.

Comment: This would be ok. I just would like to not have to resolve every merge conflict manually again.

Comment: I've upvoted your question but I reckon you'll have to deal with conflict resolutions for each subsequent commit in the history. While I've never used it, I suspect this would be a use case for https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html

Comment: Mmh. I read this. And I do not think it's applicable. Working on the rebased branch, the commits will never be already resolved for `rerere`, right?

Comment: Can you just use merge strategy `theirs` to take the resolution from the original patch?

Comment: I found another solution: http://www.davidverhasselt.com/git-how-to-remove-your-password-from-a-repository/ . Im replacing the credentials by placeholders.

Comment: @MaxNoe yes, that is a good solution. You should provide that as a self-answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git-rerere`](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) to reuse the same conflict resolutions.

The only downside is you'll have to resolve them one more time *after* enabling rerere before it can automatically reuse the resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git rebase -Xtheirs -i --root`.
Keep the first commit as pick (as you've done) and change the first word on the second through Nth line to `squash`.

`-Xtheirs` will manage the merge issues for you and I guess that's what you're looking for here.